# Crystal report page header not showing in every page

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Good Day to All!

I am not much familiar with crystal report, but I've been digging every corner and can't really seem to find the solution.
My problem is that I cant get the Titles to show on everypage, it comes out only on the first page and thats it.

I have also tried placing the titles into different other sections like Section2(Page Header a,PageHeaderSection2) and even tried copy/paste them into all of the
sections to see the difference. It was no help.

I've searched for solutions like, RightClick>Report>Group Expert>Options>Check "Keep Group Together" check box.
Doesnt work, and I have nothing in my "Group By:" list so the "Options" button is disabled.

Here is what I have:

- ReportHeaderSection1 (Report Header a)
- ReportHeaderSection2 (Report Header b)
- Section1(Report Header c)
- Section2(Page Header a)
- PageHeaderSection2 (Page Header b)
- Section3 (Details)
- Section4 (Rport Footer)
- Section5 (Page Footer)

Under my ReportHeaderSection1 (Report Header a), I have inlcuded the titles and project names which is required to show on each of every printed page.

Under ReportHeaderSection2 (Report Header b), I have a graph.

Under Section1(Report Header c), I have cross tab.

The rest, is empty.

Your kind reply would be greatly appreciated.

Jim

Comment: I think you must place in Page header as Page Header information is repeated on every page.

Comment: Report Header is only visible on the starting page as this is what its purpose is, And Page Header is repeated on every page. So, Please reply in case of any doubt.

Comment: Hi Iti Tyagi, i have tried placing the Title/Project name into (Page Header a) from (Report Header a). The output of this, on the first page no Page Header is displayed, however the last page in this case displays the Page Header but not on top, it displays below my graph(Report Header b) and cross tab (Report Header c).
Hope this information helps.
And thanks for the reply! :)

Comment: As the position of the Page Header is below Report Headers, so it will come after the Report header is placed and its area is done. So If there is nothing in the Report Headers, try suppressing them when blank.

Comment: Hi Iti Tyagi, under my Report Header a & b lies a graph and a cross tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to set this is in the Section Expert, not the group expert. There is a paging tab and an options tab where you can set your preferences. Check into that and let us know which version of CR you are running and I can tell you exactly how to do it in the morning.

Hope that helps,

Chris

EDIT:

After re-reading your post again, I think your report is not structured very well and is causing issues. In the Report Header you should only put stuff that you want to see once, like a company logo, a brief explanation of the report, etc. In the Page Header you should put things like column labels, current date, stuff that you want to see on every page. The Group Headers are for grouping data together under a common denominator (date, name, etc.). The Detail Section then shows the actual data for the group.

Comment: Hi campagnolo_1,
Thank you for the reply.
My CR version is 4.0. The tabs that i have in my "Section Expert" are only the "Common", "Paging" and "Color" tab. I have been trying things around in the "Section Expert" tried checking and unchecking several options like "New Page After" still didnt work.

Jim

Comment: Jim, 4.0! That's what ...1995? Can you please tell us what exactly you are trying to put in the report? I believe the structure of your report is incorrect and that's why you are getting strange formatting. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: @campagnolo_1 Same reaction here ("..and that actually runs on [XP/Vista/7/8???")

Comment: Hi people!
Yes, i believe 4.0 is a granny. But i dont have a choice, 4.0 is what was given to me. And yes it runs on win7.
Now i understand the purposes of each section.
What i need to show is that, 1st page will be just graph since i only have 1, and on top of the graph shows the page header. And the next page will be the cross tab, while on top of the cross tab shows the page header.
What i usually do is i put stuff under the Details section, but cross tab is not allowed to be put in that place.

Comment: I've solved the problem!
campagnolo_1,if it werent for your explanation, i couldnt have figured this out.
This might be improper, but i moved my graph to (Report Footer a) and my cross tab to (Report Footer b).
Thank you very much! And those who commented.

Comment: McJim, as long as it works, that's all that matters. If you can though, try and get a little more current version of Crystal. It has vastly improved and you would have a much easier time. Glad you figured it out!